# "Odoratus est" in Genesis 8:21

Tags: verbs, meaning, vulgata

Genesis 8:21 says "Odōrātusque est Dominus odōrem suāvitātis". What is "odoratus est"? It looks like the perfect passive participle of "odoro", but that doesn't make sense either semantically or with "odorem". Is there a deponent "odor" that means "to smell"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is indeed another verb, the deponent [*odoror, odorari*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dodoror):

> I.to smell at, examine by smelling (cf. olfacio).
> I. Lit.: “pallam,” Plaut. Men. 1, 2, 55.—
> B. Transf., to smell out, detect by the scent; to scent: “ibo odorans, quasi canis venaticus,” Plaut. Mil. 2, 2, 113: “cibum,” Hor. Epod. 6, 10: “hominem,” Col. 6, 2: “vultures sagacius odorantur,” Plin. 10, 69, 88, § 191: “bellum,” Vulg. Job, 39, 25.—

Because it is deponent, the perfect tense is formed with the perfect passive participle and the present tense of *est*. So *oderatus est dominus* is "the lord smelled [*something*]."

Note that this is the verb that means "to smell a thing", whereas the primary meaning of [*odoro, odorare*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dodoro) is "to cause to have a smell" (i.e. "to perfume a thing").